# Set different icons for light and dark theme

Tags: ios, icons, progressive-web-apps

I am developing a PWA, I intended to set the icon based on the user’s preferences (light mode or dark mode).

I've tried this :

```
<link media="(prefers-color-scheme: dark)" rel="apple-touch-icon" href="300x300.png">
<link media="(prefers-color-scheme: light)" rel="apple-touch-icon" href="ico_light.png">
```

but not work